# CKEditor Custom Plugins Button

Tags: ckeditor

I've written a custom plugin for CKEditor--successful on all fronts, save one currently:  I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to customize the image on the button in the toolbar of the editor.  As I'm a new user, you'll have to click through to see attached image; the highlighted square in the top left should have a pretty picture (like most of the other toolbar items).

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 74):

I have written a complete [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20120731132536/http://www.voofie.com/content/2/ckeditor-plugin-development) covering every aspect of CKeditor plugin development, including buttons, context menus, dialogs and more.

Comment: The plugin creation process seems to have been simplified.  Good tutorial here: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Tutorials

Comment: link seems to be broken.

Comment: the link doesn't work anymore, please update the link

Comment: Found it on the wayback machine. http://web.archive.org/web/20130208101630/http://www.voofie.com/content/2/ckeditor-plugin-development

Answer (score 18):

The answer is to set the icon property of the button settings like so:

```
        editor.ui.addButton('your-plugin', {
            label: 'Your Plugin Label',
            command: 'YourPlugin',
            icon: this.path + 'images/your-plugin.jpg'
        });
```

Your plugin directory should have an "images" subdirectory where your button should go.  In the above snippet, replace "your-plugin.jpg' with the JPG, GIF or PNG image for your button.

This answer, of course, assumes that you know how to create a button image using some image editor like Gimp, Photoshop, etc.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I followed the tutorial at ckeditor's site, which *leaves out* the icon property -- and had been struggling without how to get the icons to show up. So glad they are finally working now, thanks to this!

Comment: this works for ckeditor4

Answer (score 11):

Some info for others try to write plugins for CKEditor 3.0.

I've started by copying the source from plugins/flash and have now got a button with a youtube logo.... this is an extract from plugins/youtube/plugin.js

```
editor.ui.addButton( 'YouTube',
            {
                label : editor.lang.common.youtube,
                command : 'youtube',
                icon: this.path + 'images/youtube.gif'
            });
```

Also you'll need to edit you language file.... e.g. lang/en.js

Add your plugin name to the "common" section (this appears as a tooltip when you hover over the button) and add a whole block for your plugin, with all your strings, like this....

```
// YouTube Dialog
youtube :
{
    properties      : 'YouTube Properties',
    propertiesTab   : 'Properties',
    title       : 'YouTube Properties',
    chkPlay     : 'Auto Play',
    chkLoop     : 'Loop',
    chkMenu     : 'Enable YouTube Menu',
    chkFull     : 'Allow Fullscreen',
    scale       : 'Scale',
    scaleAll        : 'Show all',
    scaleNoBorder   : 'No Border',
    scaleFit        : 'Exact Fit',
    access          : 'Script Access',
    accessAlways    : 'Always',
    accessSameDomain    : 'Same domain',
    accessNever : 'Never',
    align       : 'Align',
    alignLeft   : 'Left',
    alignAbsBottom: 'Abs Bottom',
    alignAbsMiddle: 'Abs Middle',
    alignBaseline   : 'Baseline',
    alignBottom : 'Bottom',
    alignMiddle : 'Middle',
    alignRight  : 'Right',
    alignTextTop    : 'Text Top',
    alignTop    : 'Top',
    quality     : 'Quality',
    qualityBest      : 'Best',
    qualityHigh      : 'High',
    qualityAutoHigh  : 'Auto High',
    qualityMedium    : 'Medium',
    qualityAutoLow   : 'Auto Low',
    qualityLow       : 'Low',
    windowModeWindow     : 'Window',
    windowModeOpaque     : 'Opaque',
    windowModeTransparent    : 'Transparent',
    windowMode  : 'Window mode',
    flashvars   : 'Variables for YouTube',
    bgcolor : 'Background color',
    width   : 'Width',
    height  : 'Height',
    hSpace  : 'HSpace',
    vSpace  : 'VSpace',
    validateSrc : 'URL must not be empty.',
    validateWidth : 'Width must be a number.',
    validateHeight : 'Height must be a number.',
    validateHSpace : 'HSpace must be a number.',
    validateVSpace : 'VSpace must be a number.'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

these are some plugins for CKEditor 3.x

**CKEditor Plugins**

*Highslide JS Plugin, 
LrcShow Plugin,
FileIcon Plugin,
InsertHtml Plugin,
SyntaxHighlighter Plugin*

Download: [CKEditor 3.x Plugins](http://code.google.com/p/lajox/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty exhaustive tutorial on CKEditor Documentation Website, see: [CKEditor Plugin SDK - Introduction](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_intro)

At this moment it covers:

- Creating an Editor Command
- Creating the Toolbar Button with an icon
- Explanation on how to register the plugin in CKEditor
- Creating Plugin Dialog Window with Two tabs
- Adding Context Menu
- Advanced Content Filter (ACF) integration (on a [separate page](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_integration_with_acf))

If you are interested in creating your own widgets, check also [Widgets SDK Tutorial](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1)

Comment: The tutorial has been, and still is, incorrect. It sets an "icons" property in the main plugin, and does NOT set an "icon" property in the editor.ui.addButton() call. The latter is what's needed to get it to work. (See Silkster's answer.) I had followed the tutorial and had the same question as the original poster. Glad to finally get it working -- no thanks to the tutorial!

Comment: And strangely enough, the 'icon' property is missing from the documentation for addButton() as well... http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.ui

Answer (score 1):

To add your custom icon you need to edit skins/moono/*.css 
For the editor itself you need to add the same CSS class in the following files

- editor.css
- editor_gecko.css (firefox)
- editor_ie.css
- editor_ie7.css
- editor_ie8.css
- editor_iequirks.css

The format name for a CSS button class is **.cke_button__*myCustomIcon*_icon**

You can either use your own image file for the icon or edit the sprite /skins/moono/icons.png  to add your's.

In your *plugin.js* you need to have something like

```
editor.ui.addButton('myplugin',
{
    label: 'myplugin',
    command: FCKCommand_myplugin,
    icon: 'myCustomIcon'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding font awesome, I was able to achieve this using CSS:

```css
span.cke_button_icon.cke_button__bold_icon {
    position: relative !important;
    background-image: none !important;

  &:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 16px;
    content: "\f032";
  }
}
```