# How to add a custom button to the toolbar that calls a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'd like to add a button to the toolbar that calls a JavaScript function like `Tada()`?

Any ideas on how to add this?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I am in the process of developing a number of custom Plugins for CKEditor and here's my survival pack of bookmarks:

- [A StackOverflow post linking to and talking about a plugins tutorial that got me started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139766/ckeditor-custom-plugins-button) (Tim Down already mentioned this)
- A [number of ready-made plugins for FCK and CKEditor](http://code.google.com/p/lajox/) that may improve one's understanding of the system
- The Blog of [AlfonsoML](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com/), one of the developers, lots of valuable stuff there, e.g. [Plugin localization in CKEditor](http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com/2009/12/plugin-localization-in-ckeditor-vs.html)
- [Interaction between dialog buttons and a IFrame dialog](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=16040), with input from Garry Yao, one of the developers
- The [forums](http://cksource.com/forums/) are not as bad as they look, there are some hidden gems there. Make sure you search there, well, if not first, then at least second or third.

For your purpose, I would recommend look at one of the plugins in the `_source/plugins` directory, for example the "print" button. Adding a simple Javascript function is quite easy to achieve. You should be able to duplicate the print plugin (take the directory from _source into the actual plugins/ directory, worry about minification later), rename it, rename every mention of "print" within it, give the button a proper name you use later in your toolbar setup to include the button, and add your function.

Answer (score 119):

Also there is a nice way allowing one to add the button without creating plugin.

html:

```
<textarea id="container">How are you!</textarea>
```

javascript:

```
editor = CKEDITOR.replace('container'); // bind editor

editor.addCommand("mySimpleCommand", { // create named command
    exec: function(edt) {
        alert(edt.getData());
    }
});

editor.ui.addButton('SuperButton', { // add new button and bind our command
    label: "Click me",
    command: 'mySimpleCommand',
    toolbar: 'insert',
    icon: 'https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/5500999?v=2&s=16'
});
```

Check out how it works here: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2j3btvLo/291/)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Since it precisely and directly answers OP's question, instead of sending him to <s>hell</s> manual.

Comment: @trejder - I am upvoting this one, but I strongly believe this answer was not applicable back in 2009, six years ago, when both OP's question and accepted answer were created...

Comment: @J.Bruni Which doesn't change the fact, that an accepted answer sends OP to tones of documentation and other questions instead of giving direct answer. This isn't something for what SE was created. SE/SO are not links listings, but quality questions and answers. Accepted answer has neither quality nor a value. It is just a bunch of links with "help yourself" message in between the lines.

Comment: If you are going to do this and you want to use a custom toolbar out of your config it's not going to work unless you add 'SuperButton' (in this case) to your custom toolbar. (There's two hours of my life I'm never getting back)

Comment: This method *almost* works. I found that I have to click in the ckeditor document body to get the button to appear. Anyone know what function I can call to get the toolbar to 'refresh' without having to click in the document body?

Comment: @madisontrash , sorry.. .quite an old thread but I am using the JQ adaptor to insert ckeditor `ckeditor_right = jQuery( '.mce-codeja-booksa-text-area-holder-right' ).ckeditor();` creates and works perfectly but says, `ckeditor_right.addCommand is not a function`. Any pointers please

Comment: @MadisonTrash I know it's an old thread but my button won't show up in the toolbar. I tried both your solution and Iron Hammer's solution below but no luck.

Comment: @milfardean maybe you don't have toolbar like: insert, use other toolbar which you have, for me that allow me to display this new button.

Answer (score 28):

See this URL for a easy example http://ajithmanmadhan.wordpress.com/2009/12/16/customizing-ckeditor-and-adding-a-new-toolbar-button/

There are a couple of steps:

1) create a plugin folder

2) register your plugin (the URL above says to edit the ckeditor.js file DO NOT do this, as it will break next time a new version is relased. Instead edit  the config.js and add a line like so

```
config.extraPlugins = 'pluginX,pluginY,yourPluginNameHere';
```

3) make a JS file called plugin.js inside your plugin folder
Here is my code

```
(function() {
    //Section 1 : Code to execute when the toolbar button is pressed
    var a = {
        exec: function(editor) {
            var theSelectedText = editor.getSelection().getNative();
            alert(theSelectedText);
        }
    },

    //Section 2 : Create the button and add the functionality to it
    b='addTags';
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add(b, {
        init: function(editor) {
            editor.addCommand(b, a);
            editor.ui.addButton("addTags", {
                label: 'Add Tag', 
                icon: this.path+"addTag.gif",
                command: b
            });
        }
    }); 
})();
```

Comment: It seems that the plugin directory has to be named same as the command.

Answer (score 5):

In case anybody is interested, I wrote a solution for this using Prototype. In order to get the button to appear correctly, I had to specify `extraPlugins: 'ajaxsave'` from inside the `CKEDITOR.replace()` method call.

Here is the plugin.js:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('ajaxsave',
{
    init: function(editor)
    {
    var pluginName = 'ajaxsave';

    editor.addCommand( pluginName,
    {
        exec : function( editor )
        {
            new Ajax.Request('ajaxsave.php',
            {
                method:     "POST",
                parameters: { filename: 'index.html', editor: editor.getData() },
                onFailure:  function() { ThrowError("Error: The server has returned an unknown error"); },
                on0:        function() { ThrowError('Error: The server is not responding. Please try again.'); },
                onSuccess:  function(transport) {

                    var resp = transport.responseText;

                    //Successful processing by ckprocess.php should return simply 'OK'. 
                    if(resp == "OK") {
                        //This is a custom function I wrote to display messages. Nicer than alert() 
                        ShowPageMessage('Changes have been saved successfully!');
                    } else {
                        ShowPageMessage(resp,'10');
                    }
                }
            });
        },

        canUndo : true
    });

    editor.ui.addButton('ajaxsave',
    {
        label: 'Save',
        command: pluginName,
        className : 'cke_button_save'
    });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

### CKEditor 4

There are handy tutorials in the official CKEditor 4 documentation, that cover writing a plugin that inserts content into the editor, registers a button and shows a dialog window:

- [Creating a CKEditor 4 Plugin in 20 Lines of Code](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample)
- [Creating a Simple CKEditor Plugin](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1)

If you read these two, move on to [Integrating Plugins with Advanced Content Filter](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_integration_with_acf).

### CKEditor 5

So far there is one introduction article available:

[CKEditor 5 Framework: Quick Start - Creating a simple plugin](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/quick-start.html#Creating-a-simple-plugin)

Comment: please correct link for CKEditor 5 Framework: Quick Start - Creating a simple plugin to https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/creating-simple-plugin.html

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to create a plug-in. The documentation for CKEditor is very poor for this, especially since I believe it has changed significantly since FCKEditor. I would suggest copying an existing plug-in and studying it. A quick google for "CKEditor plugin" also found [this blog post](http://blog.tommed.co.uk/2009/09/07/how-to-create-a-ckeditor-v3-plugin).

Answer (score 2):

You can add the button image as follows:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('showtime',   //name of our plugin
{    
    requires: ['dialog'], //requires a dialog window
    init:function(a) {
  var b="showtime";
  var c=a.addCommand(b,new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand(b));
  c.modes={wysiwyg:1,source:1}; //Enable our plugin in both modes
  c.canUndo=true;
 
  //add new button to the editor
  a.ui.addButton("showtime",
  {
   label:'Show current time',
   command:b,
   icon:this.path+"showtime.png"   //path of the icon
  });
  CKEDITOR.dialog.add(b,this.path+"dialogs/ab.js") //path of our dialog file
 }
});
```

[Here](http://www.webspeaks.in/2011/12/create-custom-plugin-with-button-in.html) is the actual plugin with all steps described.

Answer (score 0):

This article may be useful too http://mito-team.com/article/2012/collapse-button-for-ckeditor-for-drupal

There are code samples and step-by-step guide about building your own CKEditor plugin with custom button.

Answer (score 0):

If you have customized the ckeditor toolbar then use this method:

```js
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace("da_html", {
  disableNativeSpellChecker: false,
  toolbar: [{
      name: "clipboard",
      items: ["Cut", "Copy", "Paste", "PasteText", "PasteFromWord", "-", "Undo", "Redo"]
    },
    "/",
    {
      name: "basicstyles",
      items: ["Italic"]
    },
    {
      name: "paragraph",
      items: ["BulletedList"]
    },
    {
      name: "insert",
      items: ["Table"]
    },
    "/",
    {
      name: "styles",
      items: ["Styles", "Format", "Font", "FontSize"]
    },
    {
      name: "colors",
      items: ["TextColor", "BGColor"]
    },
    {
      name: "tools",
      items: ["Maximize", "saveButton"]
    },
  ]
});

editor.addCommand("mySaveCommand", { // create named command
  exec: function(edt) {
    alert(edt.getData());
  }
});

editor.ui.addButton("saveButton", { // add new button and bind our command
  label: "Click me",
  command: "mySaveCommand",
  toolbar: "insert",
  icon: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWRRh.jpg?s=328&g=1"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.7/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

<textarea id="da_html">How are you!</textarea>
```

Working code in jsfiddle due to some security issue of stackoverflow:
http://jsfiddle.net/k2vwqoyp/

Answer (score -2):

There might be Several plugins but one may use CSS for creating button. First of all click on Source button mentioned in Editor then paste the button code over there, As **I use CSS to create button and added href** to it.

```
<p dir="ltr" style="text-align:center"><a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobicom.mobiune&hl=en" style="background-color:#0080ff; border: none;color: white;padding: 6px 20px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;display: inline-block;border-radius: 8px;font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">Open App</a></p>
```

This is the Button Written Open App over It.
You May change the Color as i am using #0080ff (Light Blue)