# CKEditor Plugins Documentation

Tags: plugins, ckeditor

I looked on CKEditor's website and I noticed that there's no plugins documentation yet.

But I'm wondering if there is any anywhere else?

I'd like to make a little plugin to add youtube video from CKEditor. Pretty simple plugin but still I'd like to know how to make it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Documentation is sparse at the moment, but not completely non-existent.

Check out my [**CKEDitor link survival pack**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957156/ckeditor-how-to-add-a-custom-button-to-the-toolbar-that-calls-a-javascript-funct/1966239#1966239) from a previous question.

As a starting point, you may want to copy and use one of the existing plugins (the unpacked ones from the _source directory, of course).

- The `symbols` plugin is extremely simple but shows the basic points of inserting HTML into the editor
- The `links` plugin may be a good starting point for how to add input fields, tabs, and make them interact (If you want to go the road of understanding CKEditor's highly sophisticated dialog layout system, that is. My cup of tea, it wasn't. You may want to just set up an Iframe dialog, and do everything by yourself).

Comment: Thanks a lot! A lot of useful stuff there :P

Answer (score 4):

Since this question was first posted, CK has added documentation for creating plugins - http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Tutorials/Abbr_Plugin_Part_1