# CKEditor add two Buttons in the toolbar which add two custom html tag / code

Tags: html, button, tags, ckeditor, toolbar

I want to add two buttons to the toolbar which add a custom html-tag/html code (like  and "")to the cursor position.

I read the thread [How to add a custom button to the toolbar that calls a JavaScript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957156/ckeditor-how-to-add-a-custom-button-to-the-toolbar-that-calls-a-javascript-func) but but it is too difficult.

Do you know a simple howto for my plan or is it possible to copy a code part from the orginal ckeditor source code (like hr-button) and customize it?

Answer (score 1):

Use this plugin http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=25546

Comment: This link can solve my problem but i found troubles in implementation of it. Is the same implementation for version 4.7 like for 4.5