# Add a custom button to CKEditor 4.6.2 instance without plugin

Tags: ckeditor

I need to add a custom button to CKEditor 4.6.2 instance without plugin.

I've tried solution suggested at similar question [How to add a custom button to the toolbar that calls a JavaScript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957156/how-to-add-a-custom-button-to-the-toolbar-that-calls-a-javascript-function#)

The difference is that I don't want to replace existing instance, but instead modify it after it's initialised. Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/paragonid/8r4gk45n/1/

```
CKEDITOR.replace('container', {
on: {
    instanceReady: function( evt ) {
        console.log('instanceReady', evt)

        evt.editor.addCommand("mySimpleCommand", {
            exec: function(edt) {
                alert(edt.getData());
            }
        });
        evt.editor.ui.addButton('SuperButton', {
            label: "Click me",
            command: 'mySimpleCommand',
            toolbar: 'insert',
            icon: 'https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/5500999?v=2&s=16'
        });
    }
}
});
```

But button doesn't appear in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also faced the same issue, this is how I resolved mine-

```
 var editor = CKEDITOR.replace(ck, {
    toolbar: [['Source','-','Preview','Print'],['UIColor','Maximize','ShowBlocks'],
                  ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo','RemoveFormat','-','Link','Unlink','Anchor'],
                  ['Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','RemoveFormat'],['Link','Unlink','Anchor'], '/',
                  ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','CreateDiv','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl'],
                  ['Styles','Format','Font','FontSize'],['TextColor','BGColor'],'/',
                  {name: 'insert', items:['InsertCustomImage','Flash','Table','Iframe','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak']}]   
    });

editor.addCommand("insertImgCmd", {
        exec: function(edt) {
            helper.showdlg(component);
        }
    });
    editor.ui.addButton('InsertCustomImage', {
        label: "Insert Image",
        command: 'insertImgCmd',
        toolbar: 'insert',
        icon: 'https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/5500999?v=2&s=16'
    });
```

While setting the toolbar, I inserted a custom command name "InsertCustomImage".
Now while creating new button below, set the same name as "InsertCustomImage" in addButton function.