# ckeditor change button icon dynamically

Tags: button, plugins, icons, ckeditor

I am trying to write a plugin for ckeditor, like in the link below
[CKEditor Custom Plugins Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139766/ckeditor-custom-plugins-button/1994020#1994020)

the problem is, I want the button to change once I click it, and change back, so the users knows something happened. how can i change the path to the icon after the button is added? is there something like editor.ui.editButton?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`$('.cke_button__BUTTONNAME_icon').css('background-position', '0 0').css('background-image', 'url(pathtoimage)').css('background-repeat','no-repeat');`

Where **BUTTONNAME** is all in small letters and **pathtoimage** is relative to html file.

To chance image path to relative to the plugin.js by using **this.path**. Important thing this.path should be outside the scope of function as shown below:

`var _p = this.path;`

```
        editor.addCommand('toggleAutocorrect',
        {
            exec : function()
                {   
                      $('.cke_button__toggleautocorrect_icon').css('background-position', '0 0').css('background-image', 'url("' + _p + '/images/autocorrectOff.png")').css('background-repeat','no-repeat');
                }
                }
        });

        editor.ui.addButton('ToggleAutocorrect',
        {
                label: 'Toggle Autocorrect',
                command: 'toggleAutocorrect',
                icon: this.path + 'images/toggleAutocorrect.png'
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

i have a dirty hack: (with jQuery)

```
$('.cke_button_COMMANDNAME.cke_icon').css('backgroundImage', 'url('+thisPath+'imageOff.gif)');
```

Where Commandname the name of the Button is and this path is a var wich i initiate in the plugin with

```
var thisPath = this.path;
```